# Take a single text from web to android

Tags: php, android

Do i still need to use JSON to pass a single text to android string for query's bool output from my CI to check wether the table is empty or not ? Here's the sample of web output which i described earlier `<?php echo "true"; ?>`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, you can use any data format that suits you, Morse code if you like. However choosing something with wide support across multiple platforms and languages (eg JSON) will probably make your life easier